# While trying to delete my account, it says the link to my profile is invalid

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I'm trying to delete my account just because I spend too much time on Stack Exchange and I am trying to request to delete the account but every time I try to paste a link to my profile into the link on the contact form it says my link is not valid.

This is the link I was using:

> math.stackexchange.com/users/402817/john-smith?tab=profile

Comment: Go to the "contact us" page [on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) itself. After all, that's the profile you want to delete, right? Also - that's not a link, missing the `https://` at the start.

Comment: Drop ?tab=profile as well, I think our validator would trip up on that.

Answer (score 4):

As @Oded has said:

> Go to the "contact us" page [on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) itself. After all, that's the profile you want to delete, right? Also - that's not a link, missing the `https://` at the start.

The link you're supposed to use by this logic is then:

```
https://math.stackexchange.com/users/402817/john-smith
```

Also, the link should be autofilled like what it did for me:

[image]

Comment: Can I borrow your image to be used in the faq item? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account/7979#7979

Comment: @rene Just make the highlighting and black out more professional :)